# Update global state in targeted component without rerendering components that share global state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to increment the z-index of a component onClick by keeping track of a global z-index which increments anytime there is a click on one of the components that shares the global z-index state. This is essentially to ensure that whatever component is clicked on has the highest z-index.

However I'm having trouble figuring out how to prevent all of the components from updating the z-index since they are all subscribed to this state via props. I'm using Redux and mapStateToProps with a mapDispatchToProps for the click handler.

I've tried a reducer such as this:

```
case "INC_Z_COMP1":
    return {
        ...state,
        zGlobal: ++state.zIndex.global,
        zComponent1: state.zIndex.global,
    }
case "INC_Z_COMP2":
    return {
        ...state,
        zGlobal: ++state.zIndex.global,
        zComponent2: state.zIndex.global,
    }
```

...in order to give each component their own z index state which just mirrors the global state, but this just keeps the z index at zero. I've tried a few similar things which have not worked. I'm not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way or what the best way to locally update state which mirrors a global state, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to keep separate z-indexes per-component and let the reducer figure out the next z-index?

Comment: Well that's what I was trying, but I was trying to use the global z-index to set the individual z-indexes, as you can see in the code. Each component has it's own z-index value in state, but I'm trying to mirror the global value to the target component onclick. How do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function `getNextZ` that given an object with all the per-component z-indexes returns the next z-index. Then you'll use that function to calculate the next z-index and update the store. Each component should only be aware of its own z-index.

```
case "INC_Z_COMP1":
return {
    ...state,
    zIndexes: { ...state.zIndexes, Component1: getNextZ (state.zIndexes) },
}

case "INC_Z_COMP2":
return {
    ...state,
    zIndexes: { ...state.zIndexes, Component2: getNextZ (state.zIndexes) },
}
```

---

If you directly store your z-indexes as values:

```
{ // ...state
  zIndexes: {
    Component1: 1,
    Component2: 2,
    Component3: 7,
  }
}
```

Then your function might look like this;

```
const getNextZ = zIndexes => Math.max (...Object.values (zIndexes)) + 1;
```

Comment: That's worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for a very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just keep a reference to the last clicked component in your state. Then the reducer will be

```
case "COMPONENT_CLICKED":
    return {
        ...state,
        lastClikedComponent: action.clickedComponent,
    }
```

and in every component you check if currentcomponent === action.clickedComponent then zindex = 2147483647 else zindex = 0

currentcomponent should be a unique id, the same kind you use for key in loop in react

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see if I can make it work.

Comment: [**DO NOT actually put references to components in the Redux state!**](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).  If you actually need to do something like that, keep some kind of ID string instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I advised to do